# I want to change the path of my target folder in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I want to change the path of my target folder in maven. I am using         C:/plugins        but when I am updating my maven project I am getting An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". Path must include project and resource name: /ProjectName

Comment: <build>  <directory>C:/plugins</directory>  </build>

Comment: Does not sound like a good idea...

Comment: Why would you like to do that for what purpose ? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am creating one jar which every time I have to copy at some other place. so I would like to change my target folder path in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <directory>/your/directory</directory>
</build>
```

Change in your pom.xml.

Comment: I am using the same way but when I am updating my maven project... I am getting An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
Path must include project and resource name: /projectName

Answer (score 0):

**You should use profiles.**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>otherOutputDir</id>
        <build>
            <directory>yourDirectory</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I have already build tag. so where should I add profiles tag ?

Comment: Its a hierarchy, you can place build tag inside profiles.